# sending message in a skype group conversation through vc#

Tags: c#, skype

How can I send the message in a group conversation of skype chat through vc#.

Though I have included the skype reference in my application and can get some chats.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need a reference to an **IChat** interface.

You can get such a reference using **ISkype.Chat** property.

Once you have the IChat reference it is just a matter of calling *SendMessage()* method.

If you like to you can take a look in a Skype plugin I wrote [here](https://github.com/adrianoc/binboo). (You don't need to understand the whole application of course. Just take a look in Application class defined in Application.cs)

**[Edited]**

Some sample code

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SKYPE4COMLib;

namespace SkypeClient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                 ISkype skype = new SkypeClass();
                 skype.Attach(5, true);

                 int count = skype.Chats.Count;
                 textBox1.Text = "Count: " + count + "\r\n";
                 foreach (IChat chat in skype.Chats)
                 {
                    textBox1.Text +=  "\r\n"  + chat.FriendlyName;
                 }
            }
       }
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Vagaus thanks for responding...but i am looking for the exact code that will retrieve the group conversation name and then send a message ..please help...:)

Comment: I've just updated my answer adding some code. Hope this helps.

Comment: It has been a very old question but now i am facing difficulties to send message to Group in Skype. I want to send first every morning. (not replying message). How can i get it? Help. @Vagaus and Victor