# Skype C# API Select Chat

Tags: c#, console, skype, skype4com

So I know this API is quite old and very undocumented, exactly the reason that I'm making a SO question, so I wanted to know how I can select a chat in Skype using the `C#` Skype Desktop API, I've done some looking around but most people seem to be using `WinForms` to make their app, mine's just a simple console application, code:

```
Skype Skype = new Skype();
Skype.Attach(5, true);

Skype.Chat.SendMessage("Hello ??");

Parser.Pause();
```

On runtime, I of course get an exception telling me I need to select a chat, but I'm not sure as to how I can do that, I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314653/sending-message-in-a-skype-group-conversation-through-vc) but that didn't help me much.

Is there a way to reference a chat easily using a specific code? etc... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have constructed this snippet which should help you...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SKYPE4COMLib;

namespace skypeExperiment
{
    class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Skype s = new Skype();
            s.Attach();
            if (!s.Client.IsRunning)
            {
                // start minimized with no splash screen
                s.Client.Start(true, true);
            }

            // wait for the client to be connected and ready
            //you have to click in skype on the "Allow application" button which has popped up there
            //to allow this application to communicate with skype
            s.Attach(6, true);

            //this will print out all the chat names to the console
            //it will enumerate all the chats you've been in
            foreach (Chat ch in s.Chats)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ch.Name);
            }

            //pick one chat name of the enumerated ones and get the chat object
            string chatName = "#someskypeuser/someskypeuser;9693a13447736b9";
            Chat chat = GetChatByName(s, chatName);
            //send a message to the selected chat
            if (chat != null)
            {
                chat.SendMessage("test");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Chat with that name was not found.");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static Chat GetChatByName(Skype client, string chatName)
        {
            foreach (Chat chat in client.Chats)
            {
                if (chat.Name == chatName) return chat;
            }
            return null;
        }


    }
}
```

Instead of using an existing chat object, you can create new chat object with method

```
Chat chat = s.CreateChatWith("name of the user to chat with");
chat.SendMessage("test");
```

You can create a group chat with:

```
Group mygroup = s.CreateGroup("mygroup");
mygroup.AddUser("user1");
mygroup.AddUser("user2");
Chat myGroupChat = s.CreateChatMultiple(mygroup.Users);
myGroupChat.SendMessage("test");
```

or create method to retrieve group by display name

```
private static Group GetGroupByDisplayName(Skype client, string groupDisplayName)
{
    foreach (Group g in client.Groups)
    {
        if (g.DisplayName == groupDisplayName)
        {
            return g;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and use it then like:

```
Group majesticSubwayGroup = GetGroupByDisplayName("majesticsubway"); 
Chat majesticSubwayGroupChat = s.CreateChatMultiple(majesticSubwayGroup.Users);
majesticSubwayGroupChat.SendMessage("test");
```

Comment: So what about for a group chat? This is an example screenshot of a group: http://prntscr.com/ctnr41 I was thinking it'd be able to select the group by the invite ID or by the group name like `majesticsubway`? :-)

Comment: Thank you, let me try it out!